# Dispaly the Total Value of the Sales Orders delivered in August 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to create a job where I have to Display the Total Value of the Sales Orders delivered in August 2012 using AX 2012 code. Can somebody help me with the code? I am a begginer and I don't know much of AX

Comment: Did you take a look in standard code how the `SalesTotals` class is used to calculate the total value of a sales order?

Comment: What have you done so far?